# Editing privileges suspended - reactivated at 2k rep

Tags: discussion, editing, privileges, peer-review

My account had editing privileges suspended for 7 days for rejected edits. I hit 2,000 reputation and I gain the privileged to edit questions and answers without another user's review AND the *suspension is no longer active*.

I assume this is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign), but my question is, **should it be by design?** If a user did something to have privileges revoked, does the accumulation of reputation points negate the undesired action that was previously performed? Does this happen with other privileges as other rep levels?

To test something, I also went and decreased my reputation back **below 2,000** and the restrictions that I previously had **were still in place** which leads me to believe that the restriction flag is unaffected by reputation, so why should the privilege's flag be affected by rep?

As the tag suggests, I just want to start a discussion about this because I can't find documentation that explains the rationale, whether it be correct **or** incorrect..

---

## Edit

Back above 2,000 reputation and the editing privileges are re-enabled. In a twist, I cannot edit tag-wikis, which is what I gained the suspension for. The suspension remains active with the same message:

> Too many of your edits were rejected, try again in 7 days.

Perhaps this is *not intentional* or there is a sophisticated system of flags, in which case my original question of whether or not this is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) has been answered and it is. Still remains is whether or not it **should be**.

---

### Edit 2

All my privileges have been restored. I haven't seen much additional discussion here by (admin/moderator team) so I guess I'll just assume this is all by design and it's okay that this is the design. Unfortunately, the one answer available is difficult to mark as *correct* because it doesn't address whether or not this issue has been discussed.

Comment: Have you recalculated your rep? http://superuser.com/reputation

Comment: Also, having that many rejected edits makes me concerned about you being able to edit freely.

Comment: @SimonSheehan on a recalc I drop back below 2k and again, the flag for restriction is triggered and I do not have editing privileges. And your concern is the exact reason I bring this up for discussion.

Comment: Once you gain the reputation to edit freely, some suggested edits that would have been "too minor" in the past are *okay* now. That's what Jeff said once (can't find the quote anymore though). I can't say if that's the case for you – but keep in mind that you want to keep those edits substantial enough and don't perform mass-edits without community approval.

Comment: @slhck the guidelines for editing are not very clear in the beginning and it is easy to make mistakes (21 day user here). Those mistakes were not the reason for my suspension. I'm not here to make a case about myself (pro or con), but the mechanic that would allow someone in my position to regain rights that were once revoked

Comment: Editing isnt meant to be guided - its more a common sense thing. You can see other users making edits all over, and follow by example.

Comment: Yeah, I can see where you're coming from. I've raised this issue before: [Decision on rejected edits should be displayed as a notification to the editor](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120624/decision-on-rejected-edits-should-be-displayed-as-a-notification-to-the-editor)

Comment: @SimonSheehan I'm glad you've taken the time to knock me off my high-horse here, but the discussion topic remains - should revoked privileges be reinstated due to reputation achievements

Comment: Worth noting here that the bulk of your rejected edits were to *tag wikis*... Which [you'll still not be able to edit without approval](http://superuser.com/privileges/trusted-user), even at 2K. The larger question is a good one though.

Comment: @Shog9 Even back above 2K, the suspension is still active on _tag wikis_ so that's interesting. The suspension affected all edits and remains effective for the specific edit.

Comment: Maybe this should be migrated to meta-SO?

Comment: Regarding migration, questions and discussion about how the site works are acceptable on all metas. Additionally, this is more of a *support* question than a *bug* IMO.

Comment: I love how you copied the [`piracy`](http://superuser.com/suggested-edits/8789) and [`license`](http://superuser.com/suggested-edits/8811) tag wiki suggestions straight from Wikipedia without attribution, thereby violating [their license](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Copyrights) and pirating their content. Did you do this deliberately?

Comment: You don't to accept an answer here, it's Meta, so it won't really matter.

Comment: **Please stop copying stuff from Wikipedia.** It's annoying.

Comment: @DanielBeck If you'd like to have a chat I'd be more than willing to.

Comment: I'm a regular on Root Access. Just `@` me there, I'll get notified if I'm not there. But there's really no need. See [this recent meta topic](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/4202/if-there-is-no-tag-wiki-for-a-tag-yet-is-it-okay-to-copy-the-introduction-from) for the community consensus on the issue. I admittedly missed the link to the source hidden at the end of the paragraph when I rejected the pivot table text (and therefore selected the wrong rejection reason), but that doesn't make copying from Wikipedia any more useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you temporarily lost was the privilege to suggest edits. As you reached 2000 rep, you could edit questions and answers directly, which is a distinct privilege from suggesting edits. As long as the ban lasts, you won't be able to suggest edits to tag wikis (you need 20,000 rep to edit tag wikis without supervision). Similarly, you were still able to make tag edits during the ban.

If you can suggest tag wiki edits before the ban wears off, then *that* is a bug.

I haven't looked at your activity history, but at a guess, you submitted a bunch of tag wikis from Wikipedia and they were rejected, right? That's a prevalent problem on many Stack Exchange sites. Wikipedia rarely has the kind of information that's relevant here. On technical sites like SU, we don't care about the details of a software project's history, or even more than a quick description of its features; what's more important is “how to I achieve/fix this” concerns.

Answer (score 7):

The training wheels are off now. Hopefully you learned something from the rejections, but if not... If you start making a bunch of edits that are seen as unhelpful or abusive...

...Then [the consequences *can* include having **all** of your privileges suspended](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110726/how-to-prevent-users-applying-a-policy-without-agreement/110729#110729).

Normally of course, it wouldn't come to this. Edits you make now will be immediately visible to other users and moderators, who should be quick to notify you if you're causing problems. Usually this can be worked out in quiet conversation.

But just be aware - the "suggested edit" system exists as much to educate you as it does to protect the site from unwanted edits; once you're editing without its constraints, you'll need to rely on your own judgement.